# Is "We're glad that we're going to spend" equal to "We're looking forward spending"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> I think, most students would enjoy performing one of Shakespeare's
> plays very much. That's why my friend Martin and I formed a drama
> group of our own; we're interested in acting. But we had difficulty
> choosing a play which we could perform. Last week we succeeded in
> picking a play that was suitable for us: John Priestley's "An
> Inspector Calls". **We're glad that we're going to spend the following weeks on this play.**

Can i rewrite the bold quote to that? I'm just a bit unsure whether my solution is correct.

> We're looking forward spending the following weeks on this play.

(The Text contains already some rewritten parts.)

**EDIT:**

To clarify my question a bit:
I knew the [thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Looking+Forward) Definition

> look forward to:
>
> To think of (a future event) with pleasurable, eager anticipation: looking > forward to graduation.

But I'm still a bit unsure, because

1. whether it should be "look forward" or "looking forward", although the latter one seems "more natural" to me. Additionally, the
   `Present continuous` seemed more suited because the text focuses on the actual moment.
2. whether it should be "looking forward **to** spending" as suggested in the comments or "looking forward spending". The first version seems very unnatural to me (although I'm obviously not a native speaker) and the program "[ding](https://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/%7Efri/ding/)" from defines the "to" as optional

> to look forward (to)

although i can't find that in one of the popular ones or on the website.

Comment: "We're looking forward **to** spending the following weeks on this play."

Comment: why? what exactly does the **to** in this situation? is the version without it always wrong, or are there also areas of application?

Comment: The *to* is not optional in this context. See, [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/look-forward-to-sth)

Comment: Because the complete phrasal verb is three words: *look forward to*. I'm looking forward to Christmas. He looks forward to summer each year. Do you forward to going to the dentist? One cannot omit the *to* in any of these examples and it is necessary in your sentence. It is a three-word phrasal verb.

Comment: The free dictionary should not have said it is an idiom; *look forward to* is a phrasal verb. See Cambridge Dictionary in comment above and also [MacMillan dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/look-forward-to)

Comment: I should have written *Do you look forward to going to the dentist?*

Comment: I think what is confusing you is that you are taking the *to* here as an infinitive marker. It is, however, the ordinary preposition, which takes a nominal as its object. In User1's examples above, *Christmas* and *summer* are nouns, and *going to the dentist* is a gerund clause, headed by an *-ing* form which may play the syntactic roles characteristic of nouns.

Comment: So-called phrasal verbs are, in fact, a type of idiom.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, "looking forward to" would be a good fit for that paragraph.  "Looking forward" implies happy anticipation -- you are visually imagining what is going to happen, with the connotation that you are happy about it.  It is a very common way of saying you are glad about a plan.

Comment: I'm not sure if "looking forward to" is the exact equivalent of "glad we're going to". It probably will be fine in this context so I think this answer is correct. That said, I feel like I can be glad something will occur, but not spend all week in anticipation for the event. "look forward to x" feels like the stronger sentiment. "glad x  will occur" feels much weaker.

Comment: Agreed that it is not exactly "equal to" as the headline of the question asks.  I was addressing the detail in the long form of the question "Can i rewrite the bold quote to that?"  I think it is a much better thing to say in this and most contexts, exactly because, as Stacey points out, it feels like the stronger sentiment.